# Azure Git deploy into site folder not wwwroot

Tags: git, azure, github, laravel-4, bitbucket

This would seem to be an easy task although I can't find the solution. I've recently started a Laravel 4 project which needs to be hosted on Azure. I've linked Azure to deploy from bitbucket when a change is made. This however pushes the files into "wwwroot" folder in Azure (the public folder). Some of the framework files shouldn't be in the public folder therefore I would like to push to the parent folder "site".

After some research I discovered you can use .deployment file to config deployment options (https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deployment-hooks)

So I tried .deployment file:

```
[config]
DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = C:\DWASFiles\Sites\SITENAME\VirtualDirectory0\site
```

Unfortunately this causes an error:

*Source and destination directories cannot be sub-directories of each other*

This would be due to the fact the repository folder sits in the site folder aswell. If I change the deployment file to:

```
[config]
DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE = C:\DWASFiles\Sites\SITENAME\VirtualDirectory0\repo
DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = C:\DWASFiles\Sites\SITENAME\VirtualDirectory0\site
```

It runs without errors but it pushes nothing as the repo folder is empty, I guess if I could get Azure to put the files into \repo instead \site\repository everything would be fine.

Maybe I'm over complicating things and I'd really appreciate any advice. Worst case I can just push to the "wwwroot" folder and use a web.config to fix things.

Comment: Do you need those files in the parent folder to be there at all at runtime?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not very well supported today, but you may be able to make it work by setting a couple things in the app settings:

```
SCM_REPOSITORY_PATH=..\repository
SCM_TARGET_PATH=..
```

This basically tells it to put the repo directly in `VirtualDirectory0` (as opposed to `VirtualDirectory0\site`), and then to deploy to `VirtualDirectory0\site` (as opposed to `VirtualDirectory0\site\wwwroot`).

This assumes that your repo contains a folder named wwwroot.

Some info on these paths [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deploying-inplace-and-without-repository)

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution that seems to work perfectly and allows a bit more control over what gets copied, overwritten, etc because it uses xcopy directly. Given a git project with wwwroot and myapp (in my case they are in the root) you can use a deployment batch file to copy those folders to the wwwroot and a folder above. The solution came from this article:

- [Kudos to Kudu: Windows Azure Websites Secret Sauce](http://www.flapstack.com/kudos-to-kudu-windows-azure-deployment-secret-sauce/)

1.) Create two files in your git root:

**.deployment**

```
[config]
command=deploy.cmd
```

**deploy.cmd**

```
@echo off
echo ---Deploying site

REM ---Deploy the wwwroot folder in repository to default target (wwwroot)
xcopy %DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%\wwwroot\* %DEPLOYMENT_TARGET% /Y /s 

REM ---Deploy the myapp folder in repository to folder above default target (wwwroot\..\myapp)
xcopy %DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%\myapp\* %DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%\..\myapp /Y /s
```

2.) Commit, push, smile

Answer (score 0):

had the same issue referred to this post a couple of times did it wrong a couple of times but got it to work.

SOLUTION

1. Using an ftp like filezila, ftp connect to your website and create a your app folder under the site folder, such as site/myapp
2. on azure management portal select your azure website you want to deploy to
3. under configuration tab scroll down to app settings
4. set the key SCM_TARGET_PATH to ..\myapp
5. TAKE NOTE OF THE forward slash \ NOT backslash /

Comment: Two years later that doesn't work :(   SCM_TARGET_PATH is ignored, git repo is always created under wwwroot, caused by app setting "SCM_REPOSITORY_PATH":"wwwroot" set by azure which is not overridable. Any update how to fix that?

Comment: Interestingly, this is the forward slash: / and the backslash: \

Answer (score 0):

Please also try to put a dummy text file in the "wwwroot" under the project folder. This will make sure that the directory is created.